socket hang up on Ubuntu but it works on Windows
This error happens on Ubuntu 24.04 and Debian 12. When I hit an API using Axios I keep getting this error, but it works on Windows.
cause: Error: socket hang up
      at connResetException (node:internal/errors:720:14)
      at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:525:23)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:529:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1400:12)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
  }


You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details, and given no context for the paste (is this the result of a command? program issue? etc)

the error happens on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and debian 12 . when i hit an API using axios i keep getting this error . but i works on windows
